# How do I fix the "Error has occured during build" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, build

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYEII.png)

So, I imported a code from the git repository and when I tried to update the maven and clean the code it displayed this error. I have been stuck for a couple of hours searching for a solution.

Comment: Elaborate on the import process and what code did you try so far?

Comment: I did a git clone using the URL from Github. I wasn't able to try anything. As soon as got imported and started building this error popped up.

Also, my computer is Macbook with an M1 chip. I even tried creating a simple HelloWorld program and it still said the same build error.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old file. Import it again and just run it. Don't go updating maven.

Comment: I can't even run. as soon as the program gets imported it tries building and then the error appears.